# cannot get blueprintjs table to work with multiple row selection and keyboard support

Tags: blueprintjs

I would like to use the a blueprintjs table with multiple row selection and keyboard navigation.

My approach has been to enable **enableFocus**, and then to manage the selection and convert it to row selections .

But this does not work properly... How can I achieve multiple managed row selection?

Thanks